# openpyxl: Worksheet does not exist (related to character sets)

Tags: python, excel, character-encoding, openpyxl

I load a worksheet with openpyxl and encounter the issue `Worksheet does not exist` raised by `get_sheet_by_name`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_workbook = 'JCR2015影响因子（所有期刊从高到低排序）+中科院分区.xlsx'
sheet_name = '2015年JCR'

wb = load_workbook(file_workbook, read_only=True)
print(wb.get_sheet_names())                 # [u'2015\u5e74JCR']

ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)       # raise the error: KeyError: 'Worksheet 2015\xe5\xb9\xb4JCR does not exist.'
```

What are the differences among `'2015年JCR'`, `u'2015\u5e74JCR'` and `'2015\xe5\xb9\xb4JCR'`? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to tell python you're using unicode:
Add this declaration at the top of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And every string which holds Characters should be prefixed with u:

```
file_workbook = u'JCR2015影响因子（所有期刊从高到低排序）+中科院分区.xlsx'     
sheet_name = u'2015年JCR'
```

Comment: I would add you can use `# coding: utf-8`, it is less pain to write. :)

Comment: You're right, @Tiger-222, they're interchangeable. :)

Answer (score 1):

My error is similar with your error, but a different scenario as below:

I have 5 sheets in an Excel file, and want to write data into the 5 sheets. One of the sheets is OTC-BT. The other 4 sheets have been successfully done, but just this one can not pass.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = new_recon_filename)

ws4 = wb['OTC-BT']
for row in ws4['A2:AA100000']:
  for cell in row:
    cell.value = None
```

I met the error as below:

> Worksheet OTC-BT does not exist.

I deleted the current OTC-BT sheet, duplicated a good sheet and renamed the duplicated sheet as OTC-BT. Then the error disappeared.